# Create own token in Solana Network

Tags: solana, cryptocurrency, solana-cli

I want to create own token on Solana Ecosystem. I found few instructions, but all of them link to pull request in [solana token list](https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/blob/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json) that isn't updated more than 1 year.

Is something changed in creating own token on Solana network or project become abandoned? Maybe I should Cosmos Network?

Comment: Token list is unrelated for deploying your own tokens.

Comment: But this means my token didn't appear in official list? What's the token list do for?